# Sequence from another scene imported into current scene causes only audio to render

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I created a "blender scene" each for scene i am going to work Ex
`"Sc_1","Sc_2","Sc_3"`

[image]
[image]
[image]

Then i Create One more "Blender scene" called "Complete" and <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
add scenes `"Sc_1","Sc_2","Sc_3"`

[image]

I have set *Render > Post-processing > Sequencer Only*

When render or preview **I see no image but hear audio**. What could cause this?

Comment: Maybe related? http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44208/2843

Answer (score 5):

In the VSE preview window (where the video should appear) check the display properties (<kbd>N</kbd>) and make sure that the OpenGL render is switched off. As it shows only the 3D view in place of the rendered output or that of the compositor.

While there check the proxy display value, it should be No Proxy 100%.

Comment: @ 3pointedit it dose not works. But what is the logic ?

Comment: I guess it would be possible to loop a sequence into itself. That could cause Blender to crash.

Answer (score 4):

Oh I see what is wrong, you cannot use a Scene Sequencer as output from a scene.
Therefore you cannot send one sequencer to another sequencer. You can only:

Image/movie > Sequencer

Scene Compositor > Sequencer

Scene 3D view  > Sequencer

While

Scene Sequencer =/= Sequencer

Comment: where do learn this? Is there any document which tells about how blender is structured? That would help me

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't find a reference however I do remember that the function was changed due to dependency conflicts. That is Blender can make mistakes calling the same function (sequencer rendering) at the same time. This also impacts on ability to use Drivers in the VSE.

Comment: @ashwin: since 2.77 we now have [Nested Scene Strips](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.77/Sequencer) support.

Answer (score 3):

From way back in time, this quote from the 2.4 wiki on using alternate scene's output in the current scene VSE:

> Sequencer from/to Compositor
>   To go from the Compositor to the Sequencer, enable both "Do Sequence" and "Do Composite". In the Compositor, the image that is threaded to the Composite Output node is the image that will be processed in the Scene strip in the VSE.
>   The way to go from the Sequencer to the Compositor is through a file store. Have one scene "Do Sequence" and output to an image sequence or mov/avi file. Then, in another scene, "Do Composite" and using an image input node to read in the image sequence or mov/avi file.

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Render

So it's been like this for over a decade. I cannot find any reference to earlier ability to edit VSE scene in other VSE scene.