# Render without video in video editing

Tags: rendering, video

I've prepared a video in Blender, but every time I render I get only the audio and I don't know why, how could I solve?
I'm using a Mac.

[image: Output]
[image: VSE]
While  rendering, what does No layers in render result mean?
[image: while rendering]
[image]

Comment: In order to help you, we need more information. How is your scene setup?Are you editing on the VSE? What are your settings on the PostProcessing tab? Please edit your question and add any information that might be relevant.

Comment: related? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27703/sequence-from-another-scene-imported-into-current-scene-causes-only-audio-to-ren

Comment: I apologize but it is the first time that I use blender, where can I find the PostProcessing tab?

Comment: I've solved thanks to this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=utmzwzyZuPU Here it's used Xvid with H.264 and AAC

Comment: I think it might be a codec issue, due to the "RGBA" settings in the "output" panel. You should try with "RGB"...

Comment: @AlessioMTX: If you found the answer to your question as you stated above, you should quickly use the answer function here and describe what you did for others with the same problem to know what to do.